# Java Tcp Socket Manage Packet Retransmission

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Is it possible to get the current retransmission timeout of a java Socket?

Let's say there are two hosts on opposites sides of the planet connected via a java Socket (a ping normally takes 450 ms.) that streams data continiously.

I understand that retransmission is managed by the underlying platform's tcp stack (e.g. Windows OS).

I want the sender's OS/tcp stack to start retransmitting packets for which no acknowledgement has been received in let's say 3 seconds

How can this be done? 
Is it possible to query what is the currently configured tcp retransmission timer settings for a given socket?

Comment: No, it isn't possible, and in general it isn't possible to manage retransmission from any TCP API I am aware of.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to tune the retransmission timeout from Java.  Indeed, I think it is not possible to do this from any user-space program written in any programming language.

Retransmission timeouts are determined by the TCP flow control algorithm(s).  The timeouts are adaptive; i.e. the algorithm adjusts them up and down according to network conditions.  In fact, numerous versions of the TCP flow control algorithm have been tried in the last 50 years.  There is a summary in the Wikipedia [TCP congestion control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control).

Depending on the OS (and your admin access) it is possible to get the OS to use different flow control algorithms.  Here are some links:

- [How to check the TCP congestion control algorithm in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/992919/how-to-check-the-tcp-congestion-control-algorithm-flavour-in-ubuntu)
- [Windows TCP congestion control](https://serverfault.com/questions/236913/windows-tcp-congestion-control)

But the bottom line is that you can't (and shouldn't) tune this from a Java application.